# Elasticsearch URI based query with AND operator

Tags: elasticsearch

How do I specify AND operation in URI based query? I'm looking for something like:

```
http://localhost:9200/_search?q="profiletype:student AND username:s*"
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

According to documentation, it should work as you described it. See http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/query-dsl/query-string-query.html

That said, you can also use the following:

```
http://localhost:9200/_search?q="+profiletype:student +username:s*"
```

Comment: ES throws an exception.
`java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: invalid version format: +USERNAME:S HTTP/1.1`

Comment: Try this: curl localhost:9200/_search?q=%2Bprofiletype%3Astudent+%2Busername%3As*

Comment: This will give you the results from both parameters combined and also from both separate parameters. What if I only want the first?

Comment: Thanks @dadoonet, You have saved my ass a**, Now can you help me with how can we use the count with group by ?

Comment: You can't run aggregations from the URI. You need to pass a JSon body (query dsl) and add aggs you want in it.

Comment: The link does not exist anymore.

Answer (score 27):

For [URI search](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-uri-request.html) in ElasticSearch, you can use either the AND operator `profiletype:student AND username:s`, as you say but without quotes:

```
  _search?q=profiletype:student AND username:s*
```

You can also set the default operator to `AND`

```
  _search?q=profiletype:student username:s*&default_operator=AND
```

Or you can use the `+` [operator](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html) for terms that must be present, i.e. one would use  `+profiletype:student +username:s` as query string. This doesn't work without URL encoding, though. In URL encoding `+` is `%2B`and space is `%20`, therefore the alternative would be

```
  _search?q=%2Bprofiletype:student%20%2Busername:s*
```

Comment: if you use AND, don't forget to URL encode the spaces so, _search?q=profiletype:student%20AND%20username:s*

Answer (score 5):

You can try bellow line.

```
http://localhost:9200/_search?q=profiletype:student%20AND%20username:s*

http://localhost:9200/_search?q=profiletype:student AND username:s*
```

Answer (score 3):

i had to combine the default operator and + sign to make it work

```
curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/apm/inventory/_search?default_operator=AND&q=tenant_id:t2+_all:node_1'
```

Comment: I want to do something like -
`response = client.search q: tenant_id:t2&&username:s*`
For this what is the correct approach in this case ?