# Elasticsearch query for matching two parameters at the same time

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene

I have to search two fields in a DB using elasticsearch where i should be getting total hits isequal to the sum of individual field search. I did it on port 9200 like this and its working. How to write a must match code for this.

```
 http://localhost:9200/indexname/typename/_search?q=Both:Yes++Type:Comm
```

Where Both is one field and Comm is another.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You need to use an "AND" query.

```
GET hilden1/type1/_search
{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "filter": {
        "and": {
          "filters": [
            {
              "term": {
                "both": "yes"
              }
            },
            {
              "term": {
                "type": "comm"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: i am using bool query. i m trying this method.Thank you for your answer BTW

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you need:
[Elasticsearch URI based query with AND operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13716719/elasticsearch-uri-based-query-with-and-operator)

_search?q=%2Bboth:yes%20%2Btype:comm

Comment: No, Doesn't Work for me